# setting CPU Limit for linux user not worked?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, cpu-usage, ulimit

basically i want to limit my users for cpu usage.

i have user with 1002 id and created a user-1002 slice file

i have created

```
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1002.slice
```

then ranned below commands for limiting cpu usage for my user

```
systemctl set-property user-1002.slice CPUAccounting=yes
systemctl set-property user-1002.slice CPUQuota=20%
```

after that for testing purpose i have used stress command to verify weather my user is having limit for cpu usage or not

```
stress --cpu 2 --timeout 60s
```

then used top command to monitor cpu usage
in that i was getting 100 % usage for cpu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wvFd.png)

i was trying to limit cpu usage for linux users but after performing all actions for cpu limit, i  have not got cpu usage limitation for my user.